# Symfony2 - FOSUserBundle set user entity field after registration

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.5

I have a user entity with firstname,lastname and url attributes, extending the FOSUserBundle User. I want to store in the url attribute the value of fistname and lastname as one strig.

Some people suggested that i should use a listener and a service, so i 've made:

The event seems to work after registration, but i can't find a way to change my user url...

servises.yml

```
services:
   kernel.listener.RegistrationListener:
      class: Apana\Bundle\MainBundle\EventListener\RegistrationListener
      tags:
          - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: fos_user.registration.completed, method: onUserRegistration }
```

And in RegistrationListener.php :

```
    <?php

namespace Apana\Bundle\MainBundle\EventListener;

use Apana\Bundle\MainBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\UserEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;

class RegistrationListener
{

    public function onUserRegistration()
    {
        $user = new User();

        $ap= = $user->getFirstname();
        echo($ap);exit();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is a slug with the firstname and lastname field.
First and last name to be used as slug must also be sanitizated to replace accented characters, spaces, etc..

To do everything automatically, you can use the Doctrine Extension, in particular Sluggable: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sluggable.md

This is an example using annotations for what you need:

```
<?php
// src/Acme/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(length=64, unique=false)
     */
    private firstname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(length=64, unique=false)
     */
    private lastname;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"firstname", "lastname"}, separator="-")
     * @ORM\Column(length=128, unique=true)
     */
    private $slug;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

    //... setter and getter...
}
```

Comment: Your approach seems to be very interesting, will try it ... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use `UserManager` for that instead of a listener? I would override the FOSUser register with my own and do something like:

```
$userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$user = $userManager->createUser();

$user->setUrl("any data");
```

It's more easy and less complicated at least for me

Comment: Yes, exactly that's what I mean I'm doing since I need to set some extra fields out from User form, also is just a suggestion

Comment: Where inside the registerAction (override) would this go if you're trying to get the user object on post?  i see `$user = $form->getData();` but that object seems to be empty? and I need it to be of type User...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i 've solved my problem with an eventlistener and the FOSUserBundle UserEvent

```
 <?php

namespace Apana\Bundle\MainBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\Event\UserEvent;

class RegistrationListener
{

    public function onUserRegistration(UserEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getUser();
        $url =  strtolower($user->getFirstname().".".$user->getLastname());
        $user->setUrl($url);
    }

}
```

Comment: It's a good solution but as I said in my answer, you need to "sanitize" the url. Otherwise you can obtain an invalid url, let's think if a person surname is Decò or D'amico. You can get copy of how sluggable extension santize the url: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/Sluggable/Util/Urlizer.php